# C# Different instance per "organization" / custom code for SaaS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5

I am writing a (C# ASP.NET API) program that is intended to be used as a SaaS. The program has standard features but the old (non-SaaS) also had per customer some custom code for connecting with their system. Resulting in a different version of the code per customer.

One solution I have for this would be to use Loose coupling. But how could I make it so that a different instance of the interface is called on runtime? And preferably without a switch-case / if-tree.

Any help on this solution would be nice, but I also wonder if this is the way to go?

In other programming languages e.g. javascript you can load and run code JIT.
Another connected solution would be to use a microservice for the parts where it needs to connect to the customer's system. By doing this I could update the connector independently from the main program.

Comment: Somewhere, someone has to put an `if`/`switch`, but you can always hide it behind an appropriate abstraction.

Comment: This is probably a bit too open-ended for StackOverflow. The general approach that I would be looking at is to use a factory pattern in your DI system to instantiate the appropriate implementation. Like this: https://gavilan.blog/2020/01/20/asp-net-core-3-1-using-factories-in-the-dependency-injection-system/

Comment: Can you explain what requirements you have that prevents using a single "switch-case / if-tree" in the startup path from being a valid solution? Also, .NET also allows load and JIT code at runtime. There are many ways to achieve this. Probably the simplest way to do this is using the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharpScript` class. Another option is to add an assembly and class name in the configuration and load it dynamically. You can than register this type in the DI Container. This is called late binding. What the best solution is highly depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could wire up the implementations in the dependency injection container and pick the implementation at runtime.

Assume you have a `IDiscountCalculator` interface, with a couple of different implementations per customer requirements.

You'd get the current tenant/customer info from the request and decide which implementation needs to be run, then return the appropriate implementation.

Take this example (I'm keeping the level of abstraction to minimum)

```cs
services.AddScoped<IDiscountCalculator>(provider =>
{
    // find the tenant
    var user = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext!.User;
    var tenantId = user.FindFirstValue("tenant_id");
    var tenant = provider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>().Tenants.Single(t => t.Id == tenantId);
    
    // return the implementation based on tenant's preferences
    return tenant.DiscountType switch
    {
        typeof(SpecialDiscountCalculator).Name => provider.GetRequiredService<SpecialDiscountCalculator>(),
        // ... other implementations

        // default to standard discount
        _ => provider.GetRequiredService<StandardDiscountCalculator>();
    };
});
```

You'd probably abstract this to a factory `DiscountCalculatorFactory` for good measure:

```cs
class DiscountCalculatorFactory
{
    private IPrincipalAccessor _principalAccessor;
    private AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public DiscountCalculatorFactory(AppDbContext dbContext, IPrincipalAccessor principalAccessor)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _principalAccessor = principalAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<IDiscountCalculator> CreateAsync()
    {
        var user = _principalAccessor.Principal;
        var tenantId = user.FindFirstValue("tenant_id");
        var tenant = await _dbContext.Tenants.SingleAsync(t => t.Id == tenantId);
        
        return tenant.DiscountType switch
        {
            typeof(SpecialDiscountCalculator).FullName => provider.GetRequiredService<SpecialDiscountCalculator>(),
            // ... other implementations

            // default
            _ => provider.GetRequiredService<DefaultDiscountCalculator>();
        };
    }
}

public interface IPrincipalAccessor {
    ClaimsPrincipal? Principal { get; }
}

public class HttpPrincipalAccessor : IPrincipalAccessor
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HttpPrincipalAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal? Principal => _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User;
}
```