# Register dependency injection based on dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm having a `dependency injection` problem for an application whose some parameters will be obtained dynamically. Basically, I have an API called `Manager` that is responsible for saving information for each Tenant. At times, in `Startup` (more precisely in the `ConfigureServices` method), I will need the data to be dynamically loaded on a per-tenant basis. I already have a method (called `GetParameterValue`) that does all the communication with the API Manager and it returns the parameter my application needs. However, I can't get some of these parameters to be dynamically loaded. An example would be the `PaymentProvider` parameter, which currently its value is in appsettings.json and would need to be migrated to the Manager API. In general, this parameter does the following:

```
var paymentProvider = GetParameterValue("PaymentProvider", configuration, services);
switch (paymentProvider.ToLower())
{
    case "gateway1":
        services.AddScoped<IPaymentProvider, APaymentProviderService>();
        break;
    case "gateway2":
        services.AddScoped<IPaymentProvider, BPaymentProviderService>();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("No payment method has been set up");
}
```

The `GetParameterValue` method receives as argument the desired parameter and, based on the url that is accessing the application, it connects to API Manager and returns this parameter. This method loads a `middlware` called TenantInfo to know which URL you are accessing. However, when the application is started, a `TenantInfo` property that gets the Address Url appears as null. All services are registered in `Startup` class (both `TenantInfo` dependency injection and `middlware`) See my code:

**Simplified `Startup` class:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<TenantInfo>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseTenantInfo();
    }
}
```

**`TenantInfo` class**:

```
public class TenantInfo
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**TenantInfoMiddlware**:

```
public class TenantInfoMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TenantInfoMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var tenantInfo = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TenantInfo>();

        var appBaseUrl = $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.PathBase}";
        tenantInfo.Address = appBaseUrl;
        
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

**`GetParameterValue` method**:

```
public static string GetParameterValue(string parameterKey, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection service)
{
    var tenantInfo = service.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<TenantInfo>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantInfo.Address))
        return default;
    
    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("ManagerUrl"))
    };
    var authService = new AuthService(httpClient, configuration.GetValue<string>("ManagerAccessKey"), configuration.GetValue<string>("SecretKey"));
    var authToken = authService.Login().Result;
    var tenantService = new TenantService(httpClient, authToken.Token);
    var parameter = tenantService.GetParameter(tenantInfo.Address, parameterKey).Result;
    return parameter.Value;
}
```

The conditional on the second line of the `GetParameterValue` method is coming up as null every time the application is started. If I ignore this null value for a default value (which doesn't need to connect to the Manager), every time I access the application by URL and place a breakpoint in this method, it just isn't called anymore.

Comment: Where is GetParameterValue called? This method could be a method of TenantService for me, not a static method.

Comment: @Michael I updated the code in the first question code to use the method where it should be called. I'm using it statically because I have an extension method for `IServiceCollection`, where that `extension method` is called in `Startup` to make the code more organized.

Comment: Is middleware what you want for this situation? Configure method is called for every request but it seems you're reading values from an appsettings file that should only fire when the app is launched. You'll get better results if you just extend IServiceCollection and use IConfiguration to map your appsettings section into a class and then resolve that class at the composition root inside ConfigureServices. I did something similar with connection strings for Dapper so the dev can use whatever connection string or provider they want at runtime.

Comment: This seems like a job that's better abstracted to an `IPaymentProvider` factory

Comment: @abdusco would you have a link to an example I can use? Please :)

Comment: @GHDevOps I hadn't thought about the possibility of middleware but now it seems to be a great alternative. Do you have any examples that I can use as a basis?

Comment: @LeomardeSouza Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68576620/5298150

Comment: My connection string example: https://github.com/B-Richie/Dapper_DAL/blob/master/Dapper_DAL/Dapper_DAL/BaseService/ConnectionStringConfiguration.cs